# How to call function of main activity in custom View class?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-custom-view

So far as I've searched, you can make an `onClick` listener on custom view to achieve such task.

My problem is, **don't** like just clicking will solve, what I want is to call any function at any specific operation complete or starts of custom view for example.

In xml :

```
custom:onMyTaskComplete="mainFunction"

custom:onMyTaskStart="mainFunction1"
```

In main activity there are two functions that will be called on these operations. I've been searching like crazy and couldn't find any solution or hints help is appreciated thanks.

Comment: You should implements interface to interact with activity from your custom class.

Comment: You need to create an observer.
Please read about it. it will help you to create the callbacks that you need to implement.